# Docker + rails 4 :, weird error during : RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, docker, dockerfile

trying to deploy a rails4 app using Docker, I have in the following Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qy software-properties-common

RUN apt-add-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Ruby and dependencies
RUN apt-get install -qy curl nodejs libmysqlclient-dev libsqlite3-dev libpq-dev build-essential \
                        ruby2.2 ruby2.2-dev
RUN gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc

# Cache bundle install
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --without development test

# Add rails project to project directory
ADD ./ /rails

# set WORKDIR
WORKDIR /rails

RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Publish port 8080
EXPOSE 8080
```

and in my docker-compose.ml, my service we is defined such a way that it's  building it using this Dockerfile

```
....
web:
  build: .
  ....
```

But the build is failing :

```
service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

according to the console, the error is :

```
 ---> Running in 32c12f52e507
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in 
`block in materialize': Could not find debug_inspector-0.0.2 in any of 
the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I added the gem in the Gemfile,

```
gem 'debug_inspector', '~> 0.0.2'
```

I bundled it and rebuild .., now another error is raised for another missing gem :

```
var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in 
`block in materialize': Could not find binding_of_caller-0.7.2 in any
 of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I don't understand what's going on .. what did I forget to avoid such repeating errors ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Adding `RUN yarn install` prior to precompiling assets did the trick for me here on a Rails 6 app. Makes sense, `node_modules` didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I changed  in my Dockerfle

```
 RUN bundle install --without development test
```

to

```
RUN bundle install
```

these gem are required by the development environment...

Comment: Mine is correct according to this however I still get this error with gems that clearly show as "Installed" in the output of docker build :(